# React Navigation: Detect to which screen the app was navigated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-props

I have 2 components:

1. Dashboard - entry point of the app
2. Posts

In Dashboard there's an API call in componentDidMount. 
In Posts component, after receiving posts I navigate to Dashboard. Is it possible to detect if the app was navigated from Posts to Dashboard and remove API call in componentDidMount.

Check the code below:

```
// Dashboard.js

 componentDidMount() {
   this.handleApiCall(); // default axios get request
// Here I need to detect if the user was navigated to Dashboard from Posts or other component
}


// Posts.js
  handleNavigation = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false,
    });
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard');
 };
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can pass  parameter from `posts.js`?       `this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { fromPosts: true })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing the parameters from `Posts.js`

```
// Dashboard.js
componentDidMount() {

   const { navigation } = this.props;
   const fromPosts = navigation.getParam('fromPosts', false);
   if(!fromPosts) {
     this.handleApiCall(); // default axios get request
   }

}


// Posts.js
handleNavigation = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: false,
    });

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard', {fromPosts: true});
 };
```